# OrgChart; fixed horizontal positioning? And drawing lines?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

Alright so I'm stuck on two issues with my OrgChart. The OrgChart has all of the elements it needs but now I'm not sure how to finish it. Basically, I've separated the chart into rows that determine the level of power a particular member of the chart has (level1, level2, etc...), from there I don't know how to correctly position elements from level3 over an element from level 4 int he right position or if it's even possible to do with the current HTML I've written.

***[SEE LINKS BELOW FOR CODEPEN AND IMAGE DEPICTION]***

---

**Horizontal Positioning**
I'm trying to position my elements in two different cases:
In one case, the parent element will simply sit vertically in line with a child element of choice.
In the second case, I need the parent element to sit centered between two particular child elements.

**Lines**
I need some way to draw lines from parents to children. Any method will work (CSS-based, JS-based) but I have absolutely no good way of doing this. The real problem is going to be maintaining the lines if the site size changes.

**Responsiveness**
Not a huge part of the design just yet but I would like to keep this in mind... Even right now it sucks for responsiveness. I'm thinking that my best option is to completely change the layout of the blocks at certain sizes via JS but I'm still not sure if that's a good idea or not. Any thoughts on this would be nice but it's not necessarily a big part of what I need to work out right now.

Last but not least, [the current code](http://codepen.io/jacob_johnson/pen/Oymvap)...
And an [image depicting](http://i.imgur.com/6bf8w8N.png) what I'm trying to accomplish.

Thanks so much.

```
<div class="content">
    <figure class="org-chart cf">
        <ul class="dcca">
            <li>
                <ul class="level1">
                    <li><a class="employee" href="#dir"><span>Director</span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="level2">
                    <li><a class="employee" href="#ad"><span>Assistant to the Director</span></a></li>
                    <li><a class="employee" href="#dd"><span>Deputy Director</span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="level3">
                    <li><a class="employee" href="#senior-ad1"><span>Senior Associate Director</span></a></li>
                    <li><a class="employee" href="#senior-ad2"><span>Senior Associate Director</span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="level4">
                    <li><a class="employee" href="#associate-d1"><span>Associate Director</span></a></li>
                    <li><a class="employee" href="#associate-d2"><span>Associate Director</span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="level5">
                    <li><a class="employee" href="#deputy-ad"><span>Deputy Associate Director</span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="level6">
                    <li><a class="employee" href="#assistant-d1"><span>Assistant Director</span></a></li>
                    <li><a class="employee" href="#assistant-d2"><span>Assistant Director</span></a></li>
                    <li><a class="employee" href="#assistant-d3"><span>Assistant Director</span></a></li>
                    <li><a class="employee" href="#assistant-d4"><span>Assistant Director</span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="level7">
                    <li><a class="employee" href="#consumer-laws"><span>Consumer Laws & Regulations</span></a></li>

                    <li><a class="employee" href="#examiner-training"><span>Examiner Training</span></a></li>
                    <li><a class="employee" href="#supervision-admin"><span>Supervision Administration</span></a></li>
                    <li><a class="employee" href="#bank-oversight"><span>Reserve Bank Oversight</span></a></li>

                    <li><a class="employee" href="#fair-lending"><span>Fair Lending Enforcement</span></a></li>
                    <li><a class="employee" href="#unfair-acts"><span>Unfair & Deceptive Acts or Practices Enforcement</span></a></li>
                    <li><a class="employee" href="#supervisory-policy"><span>Supervisory Policy & Outreach</span></a></li>
                    <li><a class="employee" href="#applications"><span>Applications</span></a></li>

                    <li><a class="employee" href="#community-dev"><span>Community Development</span></a></li>
                    <li><a class="employee" href="#policy-analysis"><span>Policy Analysis</span></a></li>

                    <li><a class="employee" href="#consumer-research"><span>Consumer & Community Development Research</span></a></li>
                    <li><a class="employee" href="#info-mgmt"><span>Information Management</span></a></li>

                    <li><a class="employee" href="#admin"><span>Administration</span></a></li>
                    <li><a class="employee" href="#tech-dev"><span>Technology Development</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </figure>
</div>
```

---

```
* {
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
}

.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

.content {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

ul a {
    display: block;
    background: #ccc;
    border: 4px solid #000;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: .7em;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333;
    height: 70px;
    margin-bottom: -26px;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 9px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    -webkit-transition: all linear .1s;
    -moz-transition: all linear .1s;
    transition: all linear .1s;
}

ul a span {
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -0.7em;
    display: block;
}

.employee:hover {
    border: 4px solid blue;
}

.level1 > li > a{
    width: 70px;
    margin: auto;
}


.level2 > li > a {
    width: 70px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
}

.level3 > li > a {
    width: 70px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
}

.level4 > li > a {
    width: 70px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
}

.level5 > li > a {
    width: 70px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
}

.level6 > li > a {
    width: 70px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
}

.level7 > li > a {
    width: 70px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
}

.level2 {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.level3 {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.level4 {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.level5 {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.level6 {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.level7 {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

ul.dcca {
  text-align:center;
}

ul.dcca li {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: If you're interested, Google has a page on building org charts for the web: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart?hl=en

Comment: Unfortunately I'm trying to avoid using outside libraries. I wanna keep it HTML/CSS/JavaScript only. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I got your points. [OrgChart](https://github.com/dabeng/OrgChart) is the pure dom solution for your demand.

Unfortunately, current version of this plugin can just receive json datasoure and can not converse nested ul structure to orgchart directly. I believe that the feature that making use of nested ul datasource to build tree-like hierarchy will be available on version 0.9.9 of OrgChart.

Organization chart created by OrgChart allows you to expend/collapse the hierarchy, customize the internal structure of every node, export the current hierarchy, and so on.

In short, hope you enjoy open-source.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to check out my solution on github: [OrgChart.svg](https://github.com/BrightShadow/orgchart.svg) The chart is fully rendered in SVG. Supports tip-opver / stacking strategy which is probably the best known solution to create good organisational charts. I would be very happy if it helps someone. It is based on snap.svg.

Example features:

- custom styling using own SVG fragments designed e.g. in Adobe Illustrator
- tip-over / stacking to handle huge amount of nodes in one level
- it's open source, you can use it for free in any project!

[image]